# Use $.getJson To read Json File From LocalDrive

Tags: jquery

I have a JSON file on my C: drive. How can I read from it using the `$.getJson` function?

For example:

```
function getDisplay() {
    var url = 'C:\Dsecure\D7-1.Json';
    alert(url + "," + "Hell");
    $.getJSON(url).done(function (data) {
        //Do something
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make an AJAX request to the local file system as it will be blocked by most browsers security. You need to place your `D7-1.Json` file on an accessible webserver.

Assuming you're using Windows, you could set up IIS on your local machine and point the request at `localhost` for testing.

Comment: Will u please Give Some Example .. Like Where i want To place

Comment: As I said, you'll need some hosting somewhere, or you can setup IIS. Here's a guide for windows7. http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7 There are other step by step guides if you google.

Comment: I put the `.json` file in my web server and used: `http://www.mysitepage.com/css/file.json` and I get the following error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mysitepage.com/css/file.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:64685' is therefore not allowed access.` Can you please tell me what is the issue?